# Determinant of some matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, inner-products

Let $x_{1},......,x_{n}$ be a set of $n$ vectors over a real or complex field $F$ in $V.$ Consider the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\langle x_{1},x_{1} \rangle & \langle x_{2},x_{1} \rangle &.........&\langle x_{n},x_{1} \rangle \\
 \langle x_{1},x_{2} \rangle & \langle x_{2},x_{2} \rangle &.........&\langle x_{n},x_{2} \rangle \\
&.......................&\\
\langle x_{1},x_{n} \rangle & \langle x_{2},x_{n} \rangle &.........&\langle x_{n},x_{n} \rangle \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then

1. $x_{1},......,x_{n}$ are Linearly independent iff $\det A=0$
2. $x_{1},......,x_{n}$ are Linearly independent iff $\det A>0$
3. $\det A \geq0,$ always
4. $\det A\leq0,$ always

I think option 2 and 3 is correct but how can i approach this kind of question. thanks in advance.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408307/proof-det-pmatrix-langle-v-i-v-j-rangle-neq0-iff-v-1-dots-v-n-t?rq=1