# Show that there is exactly one vector $\alpha \ \text{in} \ V \text{such that} (\alpha_i|\alpha) =c_i $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,.....,\alpha_n\}. $

Let $(\ | \ ) $ be an inner product on $V$. If $c_1,c_2,...,c_n $ are any scalars in the field. Then show that there is exactly one vector $\alpha \ \text{in} \ V \ \text{such that} (\alpha_i|\alpha) =c_i, \ i=1 \ldots n. $

I have been stuck on this for almost two days now. Looking for hints.

Comment: By the way what's the syntax for the basis symbol?

Comment: What does $j$ represent in $(\alpha_i , \alpha_j)$?

Comment: @PaulAljabar. Sorry it's a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: What does "$\;1(1)n\;$" mean ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: it means that $i=1,2,...,n$.

Comment: @JohnathanG Thanks...but why then don't you simply write that: $\;1,\ldots,n\;$ ?

Comment: It's because I use the other notation usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the notation $<\cdot, \cdot>$ to denote the inner product.

We have a basis so each vector in the space $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the basis vectors $\{\alpha_{1}, \ldots , \alpha_{n}\}$.
The coordinates of a vector determine the weights to use in the linear combination.

Let $v$ be a vector with coordinates $r = (r_{1}, \ldots, r_{n})^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, i.e. we have

$$
v = r_{1} \alpha_{1} + \ldots + r_{n} \alpha_{n}
$$

We can represent the inner products $<\alpha_{i}, v>$ using the coordinate representation of $v$ because the inner product is linear:

$$
<\alpha_{i}, v> 
= r_{1} <\alpha_{i}, \alpha_{1}> + \ldots + r_{n} <\alpha_{i}, \alpha_{n}>
$$

A vector containing all the $<\alpha_{i}, v>$, for $1 \le i \le n$, can be obtained by pre-multiplying $r$ by a matrix $A$ where $A_{ij} = <\alpha_{i}, \alpha_{j}>$.

The $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is the Gramian matrix for the set of vectors $\{\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}\}$. It is non-singular because the vectors in the set are linearly independent
[(link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/gram-matrix-invertible-iff-set-of-vectors-linearly-independent)
.

If we collect the values of $c_{i}$ described in the question into a vector, $c = (c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n})^{T}$, 
we can ask whether  we can solve uniquely for $r$ in the equation $Ar = c$. The answer is yes because $A$ is invertible.

Given that we can obtain a unique set of coordinates $r$, we can deduce that there is a unique vector in  $V$ corresponding to these coordinates. This is due to the isomorphism between $V$ and the space of its coordinates $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: How did you get $<\alpha_i, v>=c_i$?

Comment: The vector you write as $\alpha$, I am calling $v$. It is just a vector that satisfies the property given in the question.

Comment: But you've not demonstrated that such a vector exists.

Comment: If you can show that $A$ is full rank, then you can solve $Ar = c$ - then you have the vector $v$.

Comment: Oh yes. After this the uniqueness follows because the basis vectors are independent and the system $AX=0$ has only the trivial solution. Thanks a lot. I should've thought of it as a system of equations.

Comment: This is weird: the answer says "we're are given that $\;\langle \alpha_i,\,v\rangle=c_i\;$ ..." , yet this is exactly what must be proved ! Nevertheless, the OP accepted this answer. Oh, well...

Comment: My bad, have proved something slightly different. Namely that it there is a vector with the property​ (gives the $c_i$ when hit with the $\alpha_i$) then there isn't another. I should have phrased it as "can we solve uniquely for $r$ in $A r = c$?" The answer is yes, and a unique $r$ provides a unique vector in the original vector space, because of the isomorphism between a vector space and the $R^n$ space of its coordinates.

Comment: Okay, hopefully have fixed now ...

Answer (score 0):

**Fill in details**

First, there exists a unique linear functional $\;f\in V^*\;$ s.t. $\;f(\alpha_i)=c_i\;$ .

Next, [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5101/Orthog%20p10-11.pdf) tells us there exists a unique vector $\;\alpha\in V\;$ s.t.

$$\;f(\alpha_i)=\langle\alpha_i,\,\alpha\rangle\;$$

Comment: This exercise is before orthonormal basis is introduced in the book. It's from Hoffman kunze.