# Invertibility of Gram Matrix - Proof

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-rank

I'm an undergrad that just got introduced to ordinary least squares and am trying to understand why a Gram matrix is invertible only if the column vectors are linearly independent. The thread below (3rd post ) uses the exact same proof as my lecturer. However, there is still something that is not clear for me which probably is something silly.

[Gram matrix invertible iff set of vectors linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/gram-matrix-invertible-iff-set-of-vectors-linearly-independent)

> JasonMond's "only if" part is not as general as it should, because
>   s/he assumes that AA is square. In the following, I complete the proof
>   that holds whether AA is square or not.
>
> Let $G=A^TA$. If the column vectors of $A$ are linearly dependent,
>   there exists a vector $u≠0$ such that
>
> $Au = 0$
>
> It follows that
>
> $0=A^TAu=Gu$

So i understand that if the column vectors of A are linearly dependent, then I can find a non-zero vector u such that $Au=0$. But how does this tell me that G is not invertible ? Because there are other vectors such that $Au\neq0$

For **any** square matrix G to be invertible, does it require the result of $Gu$ to be non-zero for all non-zero vectors $u$ ? If so, where can I read about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to the null space of a matrix. Suppose $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix, we define the null space of $A$, as
$$Null(A)=\left\{ x \in R^n : Ax=0\right\}$$
If $A$ is invertible, it follows that $Null(A)=\{0\}$. This fact can be proven as follows. Suppose $x \in Null(A)$, then $Ax=0$. Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$, we obtain
$$A^{-1}Ax=0 \Rightarrow Ix=0 \Rightarrow x=0$$

Comment: I don’t think this really addresses the question.  You’re talking about $A$ and $A$’s invertibility.  The question is asking about the invertibility of $A^T A$

Comment: @kdbanman $A$ is just a symbol. The point is, if one matrix has nontrivial null space, then it cannot be invertible. In this particular case, $A = G$.

Comment: Oh you’re right.  After a second reading of the question, I realize they are asking about the invertibility of G based on it’s own  column vectors, not those of A.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if we regard an $m \times n$ matrix as a linear map from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^m$, then if there is a nonzero $u\in \mathbb{F}^n$ that the matrix sends to zero, then there are 2 distinct vectors ($u$ and $0 \in \mathbb{F}^n$) that both map to the same thing ($0 \in \mathbb{F}^m$). Therefore the map is not injective. Therefore it is not invertible.

Answer (score -1):

So we know that $Gu=0$ for some non-zero vector $u$. Now assume for contradiction that $G$ is invertible. Then $G^{-1}Gu=G^{-1}0$ which simplifies to $u=0$. But this is a contradiction because we assumed $u$ is non-zero.

Therefore, if $Gu=0$ for some non-zero vector $u$, then $G$ is not invertible.