# Prove that $\det(M) = 0$ iff $f_i$ are linearly dependent, where $M_{ij}= \int f_i f_j dx$ and $f_i$ are real and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, definite-integrals, contest-math, problem-solving

> Let $a < b$ be real numbers and $f_1,...,f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ continuous funtions. Define an $n$ by $n$ matrix $M = (m_{ij})_{i,j = 1,...,n}$ where
> $$m_{ij} = \int_a^bf_i(x)f_j(x)dx. $$
> Prove that
> $$\det(M) = 0 \iff f_1,...,f_n \text{ are linearly dependent}.$$

Since the matrix $M$ is symmetric, we know that it is orthogonally diagonalizable. If $M$ is a diagonal matrix, then one of $m_{ii}$ is zero, which means that (since $f_i^2$ is nonnegative and continuous) one of $f_i$ is zero, so that $f_i$'s are linearly dependent. Conversely, if one of the $f_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other, say $f_n = \sum_1^{n-1}c_kf_k$ then we may use the fact that $M$ is a diagonal to deduce algebraically that the determinant is zero.

However, I am not sure how to get from this special case to the general case. By looking at the problem when $n = 2$ it seems like Cauchy-Schwartz inequality may come up somewhere, but I am not sure how it would exactly.

I would like to know how I can solve this problem and also about what would be the motivation for someone to come up with this problem.

EDIT: Thank you for the link given by @AnneBauval. However, I found the answers on the link to be insufficient for my understanding. When we write $G = A^TA$, are we not assuming that we are simply doing the standard inner product as we compute the product $A^TA$ entry by entry? In our case of the matrix $M$ defined as above, how would a matrix that satisfy $G = A^TA$ look like? The link from @AnneBauval gave me greater sense of the problem though, and I thank her for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gram matrix invertible iff set of vectors linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/gram-matrix-invertible-iff-set-of-vectors-linearly-independent) (considering the natural inner product on $C[a,b]$)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your link. Although it did give me many insights, I am still unsure how we can define an inner product that is not the standard dot product and then proceed to let $G = A^TA$. By writing $G = A^TA$, are we automatically not assuming that we are simply doing standard dot product as we calculate $A^TA$ entry by entry? If you could kindly provide some insight into this that'd be great.

Comment: @CuteBrownie The result holds for any inner product. Note computing an inner product relative to an orthonormal basis for the product reduces to ordinary dot product of the coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ is the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) of $(f_1,\dots,f_n),$ i.e. $m_{i,j}=f_i\cdot f_j,$ for the inner product on $C([a,b])$ defined by
$$f\cdot g=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Let us now forget about $C([a,b]),$ and prove that for *any* family $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ of vectors in *any* inner product space, its Gram matrix $M\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is singular iff the $n$ vectors are linearly dependent.

$\Rightarrow:$ if $M$ is singular, let $v=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\in M_{n,1}(\Bbb R)$ be a non-zero vector of its kernel, i.e. $Mv=0.$ Then,
$$0=v^TMv=\sum_{i,j}a_im_{i,j}a_j=\sum_{i,j}a_i(f_i\cdot f_j)a_j=w\cdot w$$
where
$$w:=\sum_ia_if_i.$$
From $\|w\|^2=0,$ we deduce that $w=0,$ which (since $v\ne0$) proves that $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly dependent.

$\Leftarrow:$ if $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly dependent, then $\sum_ja_jf_j=0$ for some non-zero $v=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\in M_{n,1}(\Bbb R).$ Then, $f_i\cdot\sum_ja_jf_j=0$ for all $i,$ i.e. $Mv=0,$ which (since $v\ne0$) proves that $M$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an inner product space and linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n.$ We will show that the determinant of the Gram matrix is nonzero by induction with respect to $n.$ Assume it holds for $n-1.$ Define the vector $$w = \begin{vmatrix}\langle v_1,v_1\rangle & \langle v_1,v_2\rangle &\ldots &\langle v_1,v_n\rangle\\
\langle v_2,v_1\rangle & \langle v_2,v_2\rangle &\ldots &\langle v_2,v_n\rangle\\
\vdots & \vdots&&\vdots\\
\langle v_{n-1},v_1\rangle & \langle v_{n-1},v_2\rangle &\ldots &\langle v_{n-1},v_n\rangle\\ v_1& v_2 & \ldots& v_n
\end{vmatrix}$$ This vector is a linear combinations of the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n.$ Observe that $\langle v_k,w\rangle =0$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,{n-1}$ as we obtain a determinant where two rows are equal. The Gram determinant is equal $\langle v_n,w\rangle.$ If it vanishes then $w $ is orthogonal to all the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n.$ Hence $w$ is orthogonal to itself, i.e. $w=0.$ This means that the nontrivial linear combination of the vectors $v_2,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ is equal $0,$ a contradiction. Nontriviality of the combination follows from the fact that the coefficient of $v_n$ in this linear combination is equal to the determinant of the Gram matrix of the first $n-1$ vectors, which is nonzero by the induction hypothesis.

**Remark** In case the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent this method provides explicit construction of the orthogonal vectors showing up in the Gram-Schmidt procedure.